# Переключение в SDL2 раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: sdl2

Если запустить программу с английской раскладкой, то в программе при нажатии смены раскладки клавиатуры раскладка не меняется. Если с русской раскладкой запустить, то не меняется на английскую. Видимо программа отлавливает все нажатия клавиши. И что тогда делать? Мне надо чтобы раскладка переключалась.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gl.h"
#include "ft.h"
#include "sh.h"
#include "font.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "shaders.h"
#include "button.h"
#include "color_theme.h"
#include "panel_ipsi.h"

int color;
struct file_manager_item *fmi;
struct panel_ipsi *pi;
int click;
int motion;
int x;
int y;
int key;
wchar_t buf[4096];
int ibuf;

int thread ( void *data )
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while ( SDL_WaitEvent ( &event ) ) {
        switch ( event.type ) {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                key = event.key.keysym.sym;
                if ( key == 0x40000000 ) continue;
                if ( key == '\b' ) {
                    buf[--ibuf] = 0; 
                    continue;
                }
                printf ( "%x\n", key );
            //  mbstowcs ( &buf[ibuf++], key, 1 );
                buf[ibuf++] = key;
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                click = 0;
            }
            break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            {
                x = event.button.x;
                y = global.height - event.button.y;
                click = 1;
            }
            break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            {
                motion = click ? 0 : 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    SDL_Init ( SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS );
    SDL_DisplayMode mode;

#if 1
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0 );
#endif

    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode ( 0, &mode );
    int width = mode.w;
    int height = mode.h;

    global.width = width;
    global.height = height;

#if 1
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24 );

#endif

    int flags = 0;
    flags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
#if defined ( __ANDROID__ )
    flags |= SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
#endif
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow ( "ipsi", 
            0, 0,
            width, height,
            flags );
//  SDL_SetWindowDisplayMode ( window, &mode );

    SDL_GLContext glc;
    glc = SDL_GL_CreateContext ( window );
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent ( window, glc );

    glViewport ( 0, 0, width, height );
    glLoadIdentity ( );

    glMatrixMode ( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glEnable ( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc ( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

    glClearColor ( 1, 1, 1, 1 );

    FT_Library ft_library;

    shaders_init ( );
    global.ft_library = &ft_library;
    FT_Init_FreeType ( &ft_library );

    char *working_dir = getcwd ( NULL, 0 );
    int len_working_dir = strlen ( working_dir );
    global.root = calloc ( len_working_dir + 1, 1 );
    strncpy ( global.root, working_dir, len_working_dir );

    /* цвет темы */
    color = BLUE_WHITE;
    global.color = color;

    SDL_CreateThread ( thread, "wait", NULL );

    pi = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct panel_ipsi ) );
    panel_ipsi_init ( pi );
    panel_ipsi_set_color ( pi, color_theme[color].fill, color_theme[color].fill2,
            color_theme[color].border, color_theme[color].border2,
            color_theme[color].text, color_theme[color].text2,
            color_theme[color].select_icon, color_theme[color].select_item,
            color_theme[color].free_space );

    struct font *f = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct font ) );
    font_init ( f, "assets/anonymous.ttf" );
    font_set_pos ( f, 100, 100 );

    while ( 1 ) {

        const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState ( NULL );
        if ( state [ SDL_SCANCODE_Q ] ) {
            SDL_Quit ( );
            exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        }

        glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );


        if ( click ) {
            panel_ipsi_check_coord ( pi, x, y );
            click = 0;
        }
        if ( key ) {
            font_free_texture ( f );
            font_set_text ( f, &buf[0], 21, 1, 1, 4, 0x000000 );
            key = 0;
        }
        font_render ( f );
        panel_ipsi_render ( pi );
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow ( window );
        SDL_Delay ( 1 );
    }
}
```

---

Попробовал использовать `SDL_TEXTINPUT` вместо `SDL_KEYDOWN`. Теперь раскладка меняется нормально, но все равно кое-что не получается:

```
wchar_t buf[4096];

// ...

case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
    se = &event.text.text[0];
    printf ( "%s\n", se );
    ret = mbstowcs ( &buf[ibuf++], se, strlen ( se ) );
    if ( ret == -1 ) {
            perror ( "mbstowcs" );
    }
    key = 1;
    break;
```

Так как программа работает в линуксе, то по умолчанию кодировка utf-8. Когда я использую функцию **mbstowcs**, то выводиться вот такая ошибка **mbstowcs: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character**, и что с ней делать я незнаю.

Comment: У меня нормально меняется... Код в студию.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в полноэкранном режиме?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, там есть строка if key == 0x4000000, это alt нажатый, у меня переключается раскладка через правый alt.

Comment: Да, и в полноэкранном. Но у меня используется `SDL_TEXTINPUT` вместо `SDL_KEYDOWN`. Попробуйте этот евент.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, переключается, но вместо русских букв квадраты. У меня русский шрифт с wchar_t через freetype организован.

Comment: В `SDL_TEXTINPUT` текст приходит в UTF8. Надо вам разбираться с его декодированием.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я изменил тему немного, дописав свою ошибку, почему у меня русский не показывается. Посмотри пожалуйста, я написал вроде все информативно.

Comment: Нужно больше информации. На какую клавишу и с какой раскладкой вы нажали, чтобы такая ошибка выскочила? Какие байты вам пришли в `event.text.text`? Это не должно создавать такую ошибку, но бросается в глаза, что третий параметр `mbstowcs` неправильный. Туда нужно передавать оставшееся место в массиве, куда пишутся `wchar_t`. Еще: *"Так как программа работает в линуксе, то по умолчанию кодировка utf-8."* - Дело не в линуксе. На винде строки в `SDL_TEXTINPUT` тоже в utf-8 приходят.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat все работает, я добавил setlocale и все заработало, спасибо за уделенное время.